# Template method pattern with arbitrary exception throwing

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say I have an abstract class `Base` that has a concrete method `execute` and three abstract methods `stepOne`, `stepTwo` and `stepThree`...

```
public abstract class Base {
    protected abstract void stepOne();
    protected abstract void stepTwo();
    protected abstract void stepThree();

    public final void execute() {
        //do stuff
        stepOne();
        //do stuff
        stepTwo();
        //do stuff
        stepThree();
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

...and is subclassed by a concrete class `Sub1`

```
public class Sub1 extends Base {
    protected void stepOne() {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepTwo() {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepThree() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now let's suppose I have a second subclass `Sub2` that can throw a checked exception in `stepOne` and `stepTwo`

```
public class Sub2 extends Base {
    protected void stepOne() throws Exception1 {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepTwo() throws Exception2 {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepThree() {
        //...
    }
}
```

I would like to use these classes as follows:

```
Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
try {
    s1.execute();
} catch (Exception1 e1) {
    //handle e1
} catch (Exception2 e2) {
    //handle e2
}

Sub2 s2 = new Sub2();
s2.execute();
```

Clearly this doesn't work since the methods in `Base` aren't declared with any exceptions.

How can I have arbitrary exception throwing in the implementing classes?
Is there a way without having to declare `execute` with `throws Exception` and always having to use a try-catch for it?
I'd also like to avoid duplicating the common logic in `execute` into its subclasses.
What's the best solution here? Is there a better design pattern for this?

Comment: "*Is there a way without having to declare `execute` with `throws Exception` and always having to use a try-catch for it?*" - No. You can wrap each checked exception in an unchecked exception (`public final void  execute() { try { stepOne(); stepTwo(); stepThree(); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); } }`), but this approach seems off the table.

Comment: Using `throws Exception` is discouraged because it creates pretty bad APIs. A good approach might be to create a custom exception class `ExecutionException` and then wrap any exceptions thrown by `stepOne`, `stepTwo` or `stepThree` inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can solve this problem by making `Base` class methods throw generic exceptions:

```
public abstract class Base<E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception, E3 extends Exception> {
    protected abstract void stepOne() throws E1;
    protected abstract void stepTwo() throws E2;
    protected abstract void stepThree() throws E3;

    public final void execute() throws E1, E2, E3 {
        //do stuff
        stepOne();
        //do stuff
        stepTwo();
        //do stuff
        stepThree();
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

You can create a subclass that doesn't throw any checked exceptions by extending `Base<RuntimeException, RuntimeException, RuntimeException>` as follows:

```
public class Sub1 extends Base<RuntimeException, RuntimeException, RuntimeException> {
    protected void stepOne() {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepTwo() {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepThree() {
        //...
    }
}
```

And here is how you can create a subclass that can throw a checked exception in some steps:

```
public class Sub2 extends Base<Exception1, Exception2, RuntimeException> {
    protected void stepOne() throws Exception1 {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepTwo() throws Exception2 {
        //...
    }

    protected void stepThree() {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can use these classes as follows:

```
Sub2 s2 = new Sub2();
try {
    s2.execute();
} catch (Exception1 e1) {
    //handle e1
} catch (Exception2 e2) {
    //handle e2
}

Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
s1.execute();
```